# Ignore node_modules in Webstorm when using navigation pop-up

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to ignore searching the **node_modules** folder when using WebStorm's navigation pop-up window (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)?

This makes it really annoying when wanting to quickly navigate to, for example, the `package.json` file.

Comment: FYI. You could include directory names in pattern, see [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To exclude the directory from being searched via navigation pop-up, pick node_modules directory in **Project view**, then from mouse context menu:

**Mark Directory As -> Excluded**

[image]

Directory could be restored via **Preferences->Directories->Excluded Folders** settings

Comment: Yep, still the same in Webstorm 11.

Comment: Make sure your library references are setup properly if you do this. Otherwise Webstorm will no longer recognize functions and methods residing in node_modules. http://bit.ly/1J7XLD9

Comment: Works in IntelliJ as well

Comment: This recognizes type definitions, but not modules that augment them. For example importing rxj/Observable works, but it won't recognize Observable.map even if you import "node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.d.ts" explicitly.

Comment: Doesn't work with PHPStorm 2016.1.2, I try to ignore node_modules folder without success.

Comment: Worth noting that this also excludes the directory from TODO indexing.

Comment: How to include it back after exclude

Comment: Directory could be restored via Preferences->Directories->Excluded Folders settings

Comment: Watch out with this because you will lose library support. I have been struggling for a long time wondering why my Angular integration broke...

Comment: Not sure its the right step - since you lose the "import missing import" suggestion...

Answer (score 55):

In Webstorm 8, you need to also visit **Settings > JavaScript > Libraries** and disable **Node.js core modules** and **node_modules**. The directory exclusion will then work as before.

Comment: This works for me. However, after I disable the Node.js dependencies, all the window variables got warning "Unresolved variable...". Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @bizi I think you can manually add the libraries you do need back in settings and keep those you don't need out. Also it seems this no longer works for me - the node_modules library is added back after removal on restart...

Comment: When restarting WebStorm node_modules folder is again in Libriaries. Even if I remove it from there Webstorm is still indexing it so I restart, but node_modules folder is back in Libriaries. Is this a bug/feature? How to solve this. My pc is overheating because of this indexing.

Comment: @Hoto I am experiencing the same thing, but I know that WebStorm uses the info in node_modules to know which packages you have installed. This info is used in the "Node.js and NPM" section in your preferences. I think it is unavoidable as long as you keep the "Node" plugin enabled. Once you disable Node you can successfully keep the directory excluded. But then you no longer can run and debug Node code, and you no longer have access to the Node predefined globals, which will then show up as errors.

Comment: in webstorm 10 they fixed my prolbem

Comment: I still have this issue in WebStorm 10.0.3 - I can't seem to remove node_modules from my search index, even though it is an excluded folder.

Comment: I switched to Sublime for JavaScript with a custom set of plugins. Never looked back. The performance is unmatched and I have all the stuff I used before. It just took a bit to set it all up.

Comment: confirm still in PhpStrom 10.0.3. Tried 3 fu**ing hours everything. Finally disabling the node plugin helped.

Comment: Tried the following in PhpStorm 10.0.3, worked as expected: 1. Marked the folder as excluded; 2. Removed the library in Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Library. Don't see any files from node_modules in Go to file or Go to symbol and there's no indexing when I run npm update. Here's a link to the original issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11605

Comment: For a long while I was a proponent of Webstorm, until I started working on a large node project.  Webstorm became virtually unusable due primarily, in my belief, that no matter what you couldn't keep Webstorm from indexing the node_modules folder.  Webstorm regularly takes over a gig of ram(!!!) and takes at least 60 seconds to start on an eight core, 2.2ghz 16 gig ram machine.  I now use Atom.

Comment: Keep in mind that autocompletion is affected when you remove this library reference!

Answer (score 24):

To exclude node_modules/ files from being searched in "Navigate | File..." popup and to avoid indexing node_modules/ folder, please perform these steps:

1. Mark node_modules/ folder as excluded in **Settings | Directories**.
2. Remove "<your project name> node_modules" library in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been dying from the 20min long indexing in the larger projects

Comment: Thank you so much, it's finally better solution for me.

Comment: Doing number 2 is turning off syntax highlighting of members and methods that are defined in node_modules - I less recommend this.

Answer (score 15):

To exclude node_modules folder from all projects (only created after that change) you can add this folder to list of standard folders to ignore.

1. Open PHPStorm, and close current project **File > Close Project**.
2. On startup PHPStorm window click "**Configure > Settings**".
   [image]
3. Then navigate to **Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment > Options**.
4. Now you can set node_modules or anyone else to exclude by default for **all new projects**.
   [image]

P.s. Closing the current project is very important. If you do this settings with active project, this will affect only current project.

Comment: and don't forget to do it again for your CURRENT PROJECT once you re-open it.

Comment: The start up panel is now different in 2023. I don't see a Configure option in the new start up panel.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution for those who has library imports not resolved after `node_modules` exclusion

As the accepted answer states, you should exclude `node_modules` folder, but then you'll get unresolved references for all stuff you import from your libraries. To resolve this issue you need to include explicitly `node_modules` folder to your list of libraries

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Exclude the directory: Mark the directory itself as excluded
   (Right-Click -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded). It might then
   already disappear.
2. Hide excluded files: Tick the project pane option (under the Gear-Wheel symbol) and un-tick Show Excluded Files to hide excluded
   directories

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but I saw lots of files with "spec" on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (I can't publish images, sorry :( )

I saw on the contextual menu over the **node_modules**:
"Mark directory as": "excluded", "test sources root", "resources root"

I went to **settings > directories**, and I saw the **node_modules** with red color and can't change it, but, on the left there is list without header (?), I'm not sure if it is the exclude list, but, there is an X, I pushed on it, and restarted the IDE and it **works!**

If I see the contextual again, I see: 
"Mark directory as": "not exclude" and "test sources root".
And in **settings > directories** I do not see on the lists, but red color on the folder **node_modules** (weird), I think it is so particular for this folder.

Answer (score 1):

While webstorm tries to keep indexing everything inside your project - while if its a node project - the indexing takes forever, the better ways to exclude the node folder from indexing as below.

Select folder -- Settings|Directories -> Use Exclude - button on folder