# Mark node_modules as excluded by default in webstorm 10

Tags: webstorm

Every time I download a project from github I run npm install, which triggers a reindex on the to-be-created node_modules folder. This indexing slows my computer way down. An ugly workaround is to create an empty node_modules folder, exclude it, then run npm install. How can i disable indexing for the node_modules folder in EVERY project by default? Webstorm does this for Meteor projects with `.meteor/local`, so I assume it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

We usually suggest excluding this folder if it's used for auxiliary purposes (running grunt/gulp/karma, etc.). But we can't exclude it by default, as users developing Node.js applications usually need to have completion/types resolving working for node_modules.

If you need it being excluded from all your projects by default, just add **node_modules** to '`Ignore files and folders`' list in `Settings/Editor/File types`

Update: since 2016.x, `node_modules` are auto-excluded by default. Direct dependencies listed in `package.json` are set up as a **JavaScript Library** for completion

Comment: This is a bit too extreme (ignore vs exclude). I still need to be able to look into the file and occasionally edit things, but I don't want indexing (just like how .meator/local is handled).

Comment: Mark as/Excluded is your only option then. But you can only exclude existing folders this way

Comment: woudl you happen to know how it's done for the `.meteor/local` folder? Is that config perhaps saved to an .xml file or is it just buried in the .jar?

Comment: option value itself is saved to meteorSettings.xml file - <option name="excludeMeteorLocalFolder" value="false" />. But the code responsible for excluding certain folders is, of course, inside jars

Comment: better to **exclude folder** if you are worried about serach results just like me - [Mark Directory As -> Excluded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474970/1923045)

Comment: If you are using a monorepo with many packages with their own `node_modules`, and you decide to move them around in Finder, Webstorm will re-index all of them. Painful!

Answer (score 1):

webstorm treats node_module directory as library root, so there is no mark directory as menu when right click on it. we can change it to a plain directory by delete a config item whose type is project from preference > Language & Framework > Javascript > Libraries, then mark the node_module directory as excluded.