# WebStorm Angular integration not working

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am currently working on an Angular application and my WebStorm IDE refuses to integrate with Angular. I already turned on the Angular plugin and as far as I'm concerned my Angular project setup is just fine (project was created using Angular CLI). I even re-installed WebStorm and removed any config files but it still throws errors like 'my-custom-tag is an unknown HTML Tag' and 'Attribute (click) is not allowed here'.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Once you enabled plugin, Make sure to restart the Web storm.

[image: Once you enabled plugin, Make sure to restart the IDE]

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after searching for this problem all day I found out that I marked my node_modules directory as excluded, to prevent any library files from popping up in my navigation (when using CTRL+Shift+N) as stated in this answer: [Ignore node_modules in Webstorm when using navigation pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514438/ignore-node-modules-in-webstorm-when-using-navigation-pop-up).

However, I find Angular integration more important so I unmarked it as excluded and now my Angular integration is working again, including third party Angular components.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work for me (in IntelliJ), but didn't work today. The solution was to install the Angular**JS** plugin. I must have uninstalled it previously, thinking that it wouldn't be needed given that I work with Angular (2+).